# Can SASS merge properties?

Tags: sass

Maybe a better question would be, Is there a more efficient way to override parts of a mixin?

This piece of SCSS:

```
@mixin button {
  .button {
    background-color: red;
    color: white;
  }
}

.container {
  @include button;
  .button {
    background-color: green;
  }
}
```

compiles to:

```
.container .button {
  background-color: red;
  color: white;
}
.container .button {
  background-color: green;
}
```

I wish it could compile to:

```
.container .button {
  background-color: green;
  color: white;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Pass an argument into the mixin instead:

```
@mixin button($color: red) {
    background-color: $color;
    color: white;
}

.container {
  .button {
    @include button(green);
  }
}
```

Comment: My mixin is actually a lot more complex than my example here. I'm adding a lot more overrides than just one color change. So from that aspect, adding arguments would make things way too difficult. It'd been nice if some kind of @merge-properties{} function had existed.